# Java FileFilter Doesn't Show Any Output With Filtering .mp3 Extension

Tags: java, filefilter

I want to filter all mp3 files from a path named `"E:\\MUSICS COLLECTION"` where are some sub folders under the `MUSICS COLLECTION` folder.

But, when I run the code it doesn't show any output. I don't know where is the main problem.

The code

```
import java.io.*;

public class Music2 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   File home = new File("E:\\MUSICS COLLECTION");

   FileFilter mp3Filter = new FileFilter() {
       @Override
       public boolean accept(File pathname) {
           String fileName = pathname.getName();
           if(fileName.endsWith(".mp3")){
               return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
   };
   
   File[] listRoots = home.listFiles(mp3Filter);
   for(File file : listRoots){
       System.out.println(file.getPath());
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: code looks good, is the path correct?

Comment: Your code is case-sensitive, so if you file names ended in `.MP3` the would not match.

Comment: @HariHaravelan Yes I copied the path form the properties

Comment: @GenerousBadger I use .mp3 not .MP3. What should i do?

Comment: Your code will not search subfolders under `E:\MUSICS COLLECTION`. If there are no `.mp3` files in folder `E:\MUSICS COLLECTION`, then your code will not print anything.

Comment: @Abra There are 5 sub folders under `E:\MUSICS COLLECTION` which all contains .mp3 Files and I want to print them all. Then What should I do exactly?

Comment: Maybe [Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) is what you want?

Comment: @Abra isn't there any easy process without using File Tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're expecting the lookup to happen at the subfolders as well, you should walk the file tree

Below code should do that

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Path> result;
    try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(Path.of("E:\\MUSICS COLLECTION"))) {
        result = walk.filter(Files::isRegularFile).filter(file -> file.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".mp3"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    result.forEach(out::println);
}
```

P.S: `Files.walk(Path.of("E:\\MUSICS COLLECTION"))` won't work in java 8 use `Files.walk(Paths.get("E:\\MUSICS COLLECTION"))` instead

Comment: The `Path.of` Showing a error like `Can't find the symbol . Symbol method of(String)         location: interface path`

Comment: @CSE please import `import java.nio.file.Path`

Comment: imported already but doesn't work

Comment: Can you change the `Files.walk(Path.of("E:\\MUSICS COLLECTION"))`  to `Files.walk(Paths.get("E:\\MUSICS COLLECTION"))`
I think you're in java8 @CSE

Comment: Yes Now it's Work Fine. Thanks :)

Comment: Static method [of](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)), in interface `java.nio.file.Path`, was added in Java 11. Don't assume that the person asking the question is using the same Java version as you are.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to walk the file tree manually (for whatever reason) as described in @HariHaravelan's answer, [Apache Commons IO's FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles-java.io.File-java.lang.String:A-boolean-) comes to the rescue:

```
File home = new File("E:\\MUSICS COLLECTION");
Collection<File> mp3Files = FileUtils.listFiles(home, new String[] {"mp3"}, true);
mp3Files.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: same problem with the previous answer. It shows `Can't find the symbol . Symbol method of(String)         location: interface path`

Comment: There is not even an `of` in this code... Perhaps post an update to your question with the new code, so we can try to figure out what the actual problem might be

Comment: sorry it's my mistake. I forgot to import `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;` and the required jar's for this.

Comment: Can I use this code like this way? 

        `File home = new File("E:\\MUSICS COLLECTION");
        Collection<File> mp3Files = FileUtils.listFiles(home, new String[]{"mp3"}, true);
        for (File file : mp3Files) {
            System.out.println(file.getPath());
        }`

Comment: sure, `mp3Files.forEach(System.out::println)` is very much the same, its just using lambdas.